# How can I manually add images on Ask Ubuntu using Markdown?

Tags: support, meta

I want to insert this image into my answer:

http://blog.sudobits.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu-1110.png

UPDATE: The Markdown reference can be accessed here - https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Since SE's Markdown implementation adds to the original, you would be better off reading http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Included your link in the main body of the question since it is more relevant to Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the <kbd>View image</kbd> button to get the actual image URL:

[image]

Then use markdown formatting, not HTML:

```
![][2]

[2]: http://blog.sudobits.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu-1110.png
```

[image]

Comment: God @muru, you're quick, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can get back to finishing my answer for another question ;)

Comment: @COrNotToC it's preferable to upload the image to i.stack.imgur using the buttons and then link to the source of the actual image. This is so that if the original image goes down, we would still have a copy of it.

Comment: Sure, I will do that next time I use an image on SE.